# How to compare between different numeric types in clojure

Tags: clojure, bigdecimal

Clojure newbie here. Using clojure 1.4.0 REPL;

```
(== 2    2.0)      ; true
(== 2.0  2.0M)     ; true
(== 2    2.0M)     ; false
```

Isn't this a logic violation? If the first two are true, mustn't the third also be true?

Comment: I would suggest looking up how to compare BigDecimal and int in java. Those answers would be applicable here, because that is essentially what you're doing.

Comment: == is supposed to compare 'nums' type independently. = is supposed to also, but it does not appear to behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is `type-independent`, try this:

```
user=> (== (bigdec 2.0) 2.0M)
true
user=> (type (bigdec 2.0))
java.math.BigDecimal
user=> (type 2.0M)
java.math.BigDecimal
```

Answer (score 1):

bigDecimals are considered equal only if they are the same in **both value and scale** in this case one of them has more significant digits than the other:

```
user> (== 2 (. 2.0M stripTrailingZeros))
true
user> (== 2 2.0M )
false
```

A more absurd example occurs even between bigdecimals:

```
user> (== 0.000000M 0.0M)
false
```

I personally think this is "wrong" in the mathematical sense and have opened [this bug](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1118) to see if there is any interest in changing this.

Comment: you are correct in that thinking... almost... which I find somewhat upsetting. the equality semantics of BigDecimal where not a Clojure decision, so if you want to play nicely with the host platform this stuff happens :-/

Comment: At present time and version, `(== 0.000000M 0.0M)` yields true, not false.